# Can not call .php files after switching to %postname%

Tags: php, permalinks, ajax, pre

This

```
$('#content').load("submenu.php");
```

works just fine with default permalinks

When I switch to %postname% it does not work any more

But, I can still go though to mysite.com/submenu.php and it loads just fine

Did I miss something here?

Comment: I ended up using /index.php/%postname%/ since I had no success modifying htaccess. Almost pretty links work without problem. If anyone comes up with solution, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

What I assume is happening is when you are viewing a page with pretty permalinks, your relative URL breaks: submenu.php becomes http://yourdomain.com/pagename/submenu.php

Try using .ajax instead:

```
$.ajax({ 
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://localhost/submenu.php", 
    data: "cat=32" 
}).success(function(data) {
     $('#content').html(data);
});
```

This behavior wouldn't happen using the standard URI query because no URI segments are added, therefore the browser would always know to look in the root. Using the ajax function is a much better solution than the load function.

Comment: I tried both with no luck. Any other idea?

Comment: This works dandy for me. What error is being returned. If you're not familiar with checking for an error, open up Firebug or Developer tools in Chrome and click the console tab.

Comment: In firebug I get 
GET http://localhost/wordpress/submenu.php 
404 Not Found  210ms
but under it (response) file opens correctly

Comment: Do you have the proper htaccess file created in your root? Is submenu.php in you localhost root or your wordpress folder?

Comment: submenu.php is in localhost root (link I sent is correct). I erased htaccess and WP created the one like in http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks

Comment: See my latest edit. Are you placing a / before your file name. There is no reason this shouldn't be working. If it's adding /wordpress/ this means your location is still relative and not absolute. You cannot have relative URLs with permalinks for an absolutely sourced file.

Comment: WP is installed in my root (that is just my WAMP configuration). But take look at live website at http://milosparipovic.com/ and click on "Milos" should load thumbs into submenu, but firebug shows error; Then if you navigate to http://milosparipovic.com/submenu.php?cat=10 it does works.

Comment: See my latest example.

Comment: Still not working. I reduced it to $.ajax({ type: "GET", url: "http://milosparipovic.com/submenu.php", data: "cat=4"}); and still have error. (this site adds ";" up there, ignore it)

Comment: It sounds like a server permission error then.